# MonoTouch and Objc @Synchronized and makeObjectsPerformSelector

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, objective-c-blocks

Im just porting some `Objective-C` code to `MonoTouch` but I got stuck here

```
UIColor *color = ARandomColor(); // ARandomColor Returns a Random UIColor ;)
@synchronized(self) {
    [_annotationDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *page, NSArray *annotations, BOOL *stop) {
        [annotations makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setColor:) withObject:color];
        [self.providerDelegate updateAnnotations:annotations originalAnnotations:nil animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

What would be the `MonoTouch` Equivalent to `@synchronized` and `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock`?

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@synchronized(self)` should translate to `lock(this)` in c#.

I believe `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` is more or less just a foreach or for loop, so you just need to do something like

```
foreach (Type t in _annotationDict) {

}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. However, note that if you need an index, then you must create that variable separately, and if you want to use the functionality of the `stop` variable, then you can use the `break` keyword.

Comment: The above is just a smart and faster ObjC way of:
`
for (NSNumber* page in [_annotationDict allKeys] ) {
    NSArray *annotations = [_annotationDict objectForKey:value ]];
}`

and that again is nothing but a foreach, as stated before.